# How to set IIS to look for Debug build instead of Release

Tags: .net-5, iis-10

I'm trying to run the API project of my solution in IIS, and it looks for the exe file in the Project\bin\Release.... folder, but since I'm doing a debug build, there is no release path built. How do I get IIS to look at the build in the Project\bin\Debug... folder?

I'm in VS 2022, Windows 10/IIS 10, and building a .NET 5 API project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the web.config file, and changing the processPath to the Debug folder rather than the Release folder. Additionally, I had to change hostingModel in that same line from "InProcess" to "outofprocess".

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the physical path of site on IIS directly.
[image]

Comment: I just gave that a try - added to my path "C:\TFS\Monitor\Monitor.API\bin\Debug" (previously it was only "C:\TFS\Monitor\Monitor.API"), and now I get a not found 404.

What I was able to get working was to go into web.config and change the processPath to the path with Debug rather than release, and also had to change the hostingModel from "InProcess" to "outofprocess".